# Timer in MVVM for Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8, mvvm, windows-8, timer

I have a Universal/Portable C# library for Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8. The library will be referenced by apps for each platform. In the library is a view model and I'm trying to put a timer in the view model. The only "Timer" available in the library for both platforms is the System.Threading.Timer (no DispatcherTimer). However, I cannot work around the cross threading issues. Is there a way to do this or do I have to create a timer in each app in the page code behind?

---

```C#
public class DefaultViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    System.Threading.Timer _Timer;

    public DefaultViewModel()
    {
        this.ToggleStartStopCommand = new Command(ToggleStartStop, true);
    }

    private TimeSpan _Duration;
    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get { return this._Duration; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._Duration)
            {
                this._Duration = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Duration"); // Error occurs here
            }
        }
    }

    private bool _IsRunning;
    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return this._IsRunning; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._IsRunning)
            {
                this._IsRunning = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("IsRunning");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (null != propertyChanged)
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.IsRunning = true;
        this._Timer = new Timer(TimerTick, this, 0, 1000);
    }

    private DateTime _StartTime;
    public DateTime StartTime
    {
        get { return this._StartTime; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._StartTime)
            {
                this._StartTime = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("StartTime");
            }
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this._Timer.Dispose();
        this.IsRunning = false;
    }

    private void TimerTick(object o)
    {
        var defaultViewModel = (DefaultViewModel)o;
        defaultViewModel.Duration = DateTime.Now - defaultViewModel.StartTime;
    }

    public void ToggleStartStop()
    {
        if (this.IsRunning)
            this.Stop();
        else
            this.Start();
    }

    public Command ToggleStartStopCommand { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: In my view model base class in a PCL I use a `protected abstract void DispatcherInvoke(Action action)` method, which is implemented by derived, platform-specific view model classes.

Answer (score 1):

Two potential solutions:

1. If you're targeting Windows 8 and ***Windows Phone 8.1*** (not Phone 8.0 Silverlight), consider using a Universal App containing a *Shared Project* instead of a Portable Class Library to host your Viewmodels. Shared projects are only compatible with WinRT projects, but support the full WinRT framework. In that case, it should not be a problem to instantiate a *DispatcherTimer* directly within the Viewmodel.
2. Otherwise (within a real Portable Class Library), I'm afraid the only way is to create an interface within the PCL that provides the most important timer functions, and two platform-specific timer classes that implement this interface. In practice, these two implementations will be identical except for the `using` statements at the beginning of the file, because Windows Phone Silverlight's `DispatcherTimer` lives within the `System.Windows.Threading` namespace while on WinRT it's located at `Windows.UI.Xaml` but both have the same functionality - so it's basically a copy/paste job.

   I've realized such a splitted implementation as part of the MVVMbasics framework, maybe [the sources avaiable at Codeplex](https://mvvmbasics.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Sources/MVVMbasics/MVVMbasics/Services/ITimerService.cs) are of any help!