# How do I include a timer in a universal windows app with c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I need a timer in my universal windows app. I have read that the only one available for universal windows apps is `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`. In order to use this I manually added the `WindowsBase.dll` to my app's references in the solution explorer in visual studio. Now I get the following error:

```
Error   3   Cannot find type System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter in module System.dll.  Game.Windows
```

The error goes away if I delete the `WindowsBase` reference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timer in MVVM for Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124684/timer-in-mvvm-for-windows-phone-8-and-windows-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assemblies you can add to a Universal app are listed in the Project + Add Reference, Assemblies, Framework list.

Yes, it is empty.

That was intentional.

Because you already have a reference to *all* possible .NET assemblies in a Universal app project.  Using the Browse button is *not* a workaround.  And causes the kind of misery you describe, WindowsBase has types that can only work in a WPF app.  The kind that runs with the full .NET Framework you've got installed on a desktop.  Not the kind that a user has on his phone, called .NETCore.  It is *small*, phones are small.

You already have the `Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer` available in a Universal app project, no need to add a reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think the one that windows store apps use is located in `Windows.UI.Xaml` namespace

Answer (score 0):

I have been using ThreadPoolTimer, in Windows.System.Threading.